# Difference between arima(1,0,0) function and running a regression on lag values?

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I'm currently doing time series in R and had a few fundamental R doubts. Mainly, what is the difference between the two pieces of code?

```
ar_1 <- lm(df$VALUE ~ lag(df$value))
summary(ar_1)
```

```
arima_values <- arima(df$value, order=c(1,0,0))
arima_values
```

I have to essentially get the coefficients, S.E. etc. but the above two pieces of code return different values for each. What is each piece of code doing? The general formula for AR(1) is essentially running a regression on the 1st order lagged values correct? The ARIMA function should achieve the same thing?

Comment: See there: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/221073/163114

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They give the same values to several decimals if the arguments to `arima` are set as shown:

```
# generate test series
set.seed(13)
n <- 25
mu <- 0.4
phi <- 0.8
s <- seq(0, length = n - 1)
x <- rnorm(1)
for(i in 2:n) x[i] <- mu + phi * x[i-1] + rnorm(1)

# lm
mod.lm <- lm(x[-1] ~ x[-n])
coef(mod.lm)
## (Intercept)       x[-n] 
##   0.7593169   0.7408584 

# arima - use conditional sum of squares and drop 0 observations    
mod.arima <- arima(x, c(1, 0, 0), method = "CSS", n.cond = 0)
co <- coef(mod.arima)
co
##       ar1 intercept 
## 0.7408535 2.9300719 

# arima defines intercept differently so use this to compare to lm intercept
with(as.list(co), intercept * (1 - ar1))  
## [1] 0.7593179
```

We can also use `ar` with the appropriate arguments:

```
mod.ar <- ar(x, order.max = 1, method = "ols", demean = FALSE, intercept = TRUE)
mod.ar
## 
## Call:
## ar(x = x, order.max = 1, method = "ols", demean = FALSE, intercept = TRUE)
##
## Coefficients:
##      1  
## 0.7409  
##
## Intercept: 0.7593 (0.3695)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I see that you have generated random values yourself using the general AR(1) formula but what about when you already have a dataset and apply a 1 lagged regression on the dataset? What does it mean to "apply" AR(1) to a dataset?

Comment: There is no dependence in the answer on where the input came from.  Note the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag which in particular states that the question is responsible for providing test data.  In the absence of that the answer provided it.